# How to remove overlay over the padding area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a code like this, here you can see that I have added overlay over the image. However, this over low size is greater than that of image, it is howing overlay even on the padding area. I could replace this padding with margin and remove that unnecessary overlay over the iamge, however, this push the last image to new rows.

```css
.sb-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.sb-overlay:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.sb-text{
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s-image img{
width: 100%
}
.grid-item{
padding:5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I remove this overlay over the padding areay, i.e, make overlay exact size of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `absolute` positioned elements position themselves against the nearest parent with a position set, you can add `position: relative` and `display: block` to your `a.s-image` element. Currently your overlay is positioning itself to the `.grid-item`.

```css
.sb-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.sb-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sb-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.s-image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.s-image img {
  width: 100%
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
      <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
      <div class="sb-overlay">
        <div class="sb-text">
          This is the title
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### USING CALC()

Since `absolute` positioned elements that are children of another element consider `padding` as included in the element's width/height, you can use `calc` to set the width and adjust your `top,left,right,bottom` values.

You are dealing with Bootstrap, which automatically adds the `15px` padding to the left and right of the column.

```css
.sb-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100%-30px);
    height: calc(100%-10px);
    top: 5px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.sb-overlay:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.sb-text{
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s-image img{
width: 100%
}
.grid-item{
padding:5px;
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a data-content="Here is a caption" class="magnific-popup s-image" href="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
          <img title="This is the title" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
          <div class="sb-overlay">
              <div class="sb-text">
                    This is the title
              </div>
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a different way, I think you had added another way that might be better, starting overlay for other than 0 might not sound so convienent, espesially i need to update those if I updated the padding on `grid-item` for example if I place `.grid-item{padding: 5px !important}` everything just got messed up. I am ok to modify the overlay structure

Comment: Yeah, I rolled back to my original answer.

Comment: @AayushDahal I set the first code snippet to using `0` for all the `top,left,right,bottom` and adding `position: relative` and `display: block` to the `.s-image`. This will make sure that no matter what padding you set on the `grid-item`, the overlay will always be in the right spot. I put a second answer in place using `calc()` which is less flexible.